# How to test catch part in jest and @testing-library/react

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, babel-jest

MyComponent.js

```
<Button
    onClick={ async e =>{
    resetForm();
    }}
    Reset
</Button>


const resetForm= () => {
    try{
        someRef.current.resetFormValues();
        const div = document.getElementById("errorDisplayDiv");
        div.innerHTML="";
        div.style.display = "none";
        setSomeVaribale();
    }
    catch(error){
        setStateAndLogError(error);
    }
}
```

I am not able to cover the catch part in test cases.
I am using **jest: 24.9.0 and @testing-library/react: 12.1.2**

Comment: In what scenario would the `try` block's code throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry I misread your question.

To do this you would need to mock the document object and have it throw an error. One way might be like this inside of your test:

```
global.document = { 
  // keep the other methods so other things do not break
  ...global.document,
  getElementById: () => throw new Error('fake error')
}
```

now calling that method will throw and fall back to the catch for your test